# Are there JDBC drivers which fail to close ResultSet when closing Statement?

Tags: jdbc

[JavaDoc for `Statement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#close%28%29) is clear:

> All execution methods in the Statement interface implicitly close a statment's current `ResultSet` object if an open one exists.
>
> When a `Statement` object is closed, its current `ResultSet` object, if one exists, is also closed.

However, there are multiple recommendations to close `ResultSet` before `Statement` both on Stack Overflow and on the web in general. Are there known cases where (presumably due to buggy drivers) closing `Statement` but not `ResultSet` leads to problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible that a buggy JDBC driver could not close ResultSet. Regardless it is best to be specific and intentional so you should close your ResultSet in try...finally block. If you are using JDK7 you can declare the ResultSet variable in the try clause and because it implements AutoCloseable it will be closed automatically without a finally clause.

Comment: The OP explicitly asked if there were known buggy JDBC drivers. This answer is simply restating the question. Oracle and Mysql in any case reliably closes ResultSet's when the Statement is closed.